# Not able to update shadowLastChange value for LDAP

Tags: linux, ldap, password

On changing password of a user shadowLastChange value is not getting changed. Any way to change it manually ?

```
 objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
shadowLastChange: **14876**
shadowMax: 90
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 505
```

What format is this shadowLastChange ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RFC 2307, aka nis.schema:

```
( nisSchema.1.5 NAME 'shadowLastChange'
  EQUALITY integerMatch
  SYNTAX 'INTEGER' SINGLE-VALUE )
```

The value of the integer is not defined in the RFC but is taken from that of `/etc/shadow` so is the number of *days* since the Unix epoch.

You should be able to change it with ldapmodify(1), unless your LDAP server is configured to restrict access to this attribute and enforce it with some local policy.

Comment: yes I am able to modify with ldapmodify. but should it change automatically when we update password.

Comment: This is accomplished one of two ways: trusting the PAM modules on the client side to do this, or having the server update things automatically, and that's server-specific.  You don't mention which server software you're running.